# Google Charts interpolateNulls not working

Tags: javascript, json, charts, google-visualization

I cannot create a graph with interpolateNull option. Should be correct but cannot draw the lines between missing points.
The data is collected from a php-json. here the Example and the data provided by the json.
html-javascript page:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line', 'corechart']});
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
            function drawChart() {
                    $.ajax({
                            url: 'http://192.168.1.50/fetch_data.php?type=line2',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function (jsonData) {
                                    var chartDiv = document.getElementById('chart_div');
                                    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
                                    // create formatter
                                    var formatNumber = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({pattern: '#,##0.00'});
                                    // format column 1 - Pressure
                                    formatNumber.format(data, 1);
                                    // format column 2 - Temperature
                                    formatNumber.format(data, 2);
                                    var materialOptions = {
                                            chart: {
                                                    title: 'Average Pressure and Temperatures'
                                            },
                                            vAxis: {
                                                    format: '#,##0.00'
                                            },
                                            width: 1200,
                                            height: 600,
                                            interpolateNulls: true,
                                            series: {
                                                    // Gives each series an axis name that matches the Y-axis below.
                                                    0: {axis: 'Pressure'},
                                                    1: {axis: 'Temperature'}
                                            },
                                            axes: {
                                                    // Adds labels to each axis; they don't have to match the axis names.
                                                    y: {
                                                            Temps: {label: 'Pressure'},
                                                            Daylight: {label: 'Temps (Celsius)'}
                                                    }
                                            }
                                    };

                                    function drawMaterialChart() {
                                            var materialChart = new google.charts.Line(chartDiv);
                                            var classicChart = new google.visualization.LineChart(chartDiv);
                                            materialChart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(materialOptions));
                                    }
                                    drawMaterialChart();
                            },
                            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                    console.log(errorThrown + ': ' + textStatus);
                            }
                    });
            }
    </script>
    </head>
            <body>
                    <br><br>
                    <div id="chart_div"></div>
            </body>
    </html>
```

and php-json data returned from the fetch_data.php page:

```
{
   "cols":[
      {
         "label":"Date",
         "type":"string"
      },
      {
         "label":"hPa",
         "type":"number"
      },
      {
         "label":"Dallas",
         "type":"number"
      }
   ],
   "rows":[
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2016-08-27 12:51:00"
            },
            {
               "v":1020.61
            },
            {
               "v":30
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2016-08-27 12:54:00"
            },
            {
               "v":1020.49
            },
            {
               "v":null
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2016-08-27 12:57:00"
            },
            {
               "v":1020.49
            },
            {
               "v":30.4
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2016-08-27 13:00:00"
            },
            {
               "v":1020.48
            },
            {
               "v":30.7
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2016-08-27 13:03:00"
            },
            {
               "v":1020.43
            },
            {
               "v":30.6
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2016-08-27 13:06:00"
            },
            {
               "v":1020.39
            },
            {
               "v":30.5
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2016-08-27 13:09:00"
            },
            {
               "v":1020.34
            },
            {
               "v":30.9
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2016-08-27 13:12:00"
            },
            {
               "v":1020.33
            },
            {
               "v":30.5
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2016-08-27 13:15:00"
            },
            {
               "v":1020.28
            },
            {
               "v":30.8
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2016-08-27 13:18:00"
            },
            {
               "v":1020.28
            },
            {
               "v":30.8
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2016-08-27 13:21:00"
            },
            {
               "v":1020.28
            },
            {
               "v":31
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2016-08-27 13:24:00"
            },
            {
               "v":1020.23
            },
            {
               "v":null
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2016-08-27 13:27:00"
            },
            {
               "v":1020.24
            },
            {
               "v":30.7
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2016-08-27 13:30:00"
            },
            {
               "v":1020.2
            },
            {
               "v":31.3
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2016-08-27 13:33:00"
            },
            {
               "v":1020.23
            },
            {
               "v":31.3
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2016-08-27 13:36:00"
            },
            {
               "v":1020.2
            },
            {
               "v":31.3
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2016-08-27 13:39:00"
            },
            {
               "v":1020.14
            },
            {
               "v":31.3
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2016-08-27 13:42:00"
            },
            {
               "v":1020.14
            },
            {
               "v":31.1
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2016-08-27 13:45:00"
            },
            {
               "v":1020.06
            },
            {
               "v":31
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2016-08-27 13:48:00"
            },
            {
               "v":1020.06
            },
            {
               "v":31.1
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2016-08-27 13:51:00"
            },
            {
               "v":1020.03
            },
            {
               "v":31.1
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2016-08-27 13:54:00"
            },
            {
               "v":1019.98
            },
            {
               "v":31.1
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2016-08-27 13:57:00"
            },
            {
               "v":1019.97
            },
            {
               "v":31.1
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2016-08-27 14:00:00"
            },
            {
               "v":1019.9
            },
            {
               "v":31.1
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2016-08-27 14:03:00"
            },
            {
               "v":1019.89
            },
            {
               "v":31.1
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2016-08-27 14:06:00"
            },
            {
               "v":1019.75
            },
            {
               "v":31.2
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2016-08-27 14:09:00"
            },
            {
               "v":1019.8
            },
            {
               "v":31.2
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2016-08-27 14:12:00"
            },
            {
               "v":1019.72
            },
            {
               "v":31.3
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2016-08-27 14:15:00"
            },
            {
               "v":1019.64
            },
            {
               "v":31.1
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2016-08-27 14:18:00"
            },
            {
               "v":1019.6
            },
            {
               "v":31.3
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2016-08-27 14:21:00"
            },
            {
               "v":1019.6
            },
            {
               "v":31.3
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2016-08-27 14:24:00"
            },
            {
               "v":1019.55
            },
            {
               "v":31.3
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2016-08-27 14:27:00"
            },
            {
               "v":1019.55
            },
            {
               "v":31.4
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2016-08-27 14:30:00"
            },
            {
               "v":1019.49
            },
            {
               "v":31.3
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2016-08-27 14:33:00"
            },
            {
               "v":1019.46
            },
            {
               "v":31.4
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2016-08-27 14:36:00"
            },
            {
               "v":1019.44
            },
            {
               "v":31.3
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2016-08-27 14:39:00"
            },
            {
               "v":1019.36
            },
            {
               "v":31.1
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2016-08-27 14:42:00"
            },
            {
               "v":1019.41
            },
            {
               "v":31.1
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2016-08-27 14:45:00"
            },
            {
               "v":1019.33
            },
            {
               "v":null
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2016-08-27 14:48:00"
            },
            {
               "v":1019.35
            },
            {
               "v":31.3
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2016-08-27 14:51:00"
            },
            {
               "v":1019.34
            },
            {
               "v":31.3
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2016-08-27 14:54:00"
            },
            {
               "v":1019.29
            },
            {
               "v":31.4
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2016-08-27 14:57:00"
            },
            {
               "v":1019.22
            },
            {
               "v":31.3
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2016-08-27 15:00:00"
            },
            {
               "v":1019.24
            },
            {
               "v":null
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Seems all correct but the data in example on 2016-08-27 12:54:00 leaves me a hole in the graph.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`interpolateNulls` simply doesn't work on a *Material* chart
`google.charts.Line`
(even with `google.charts.Line.convertOptions`)

need to use *Core* chart
`google.visualization.LineChart`

there is an option for `theme: 'material'` you can use on *Core* charts

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function() {
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable({
      "cols": [{
        "label": "Date",
        "type": "string"
      }, {
        "label": "hPa",
        "type": "number"
      }, {
        "label": "Dallas",
        "type": "number"
      }],
      "rows": [{
        "c": [{
          "v": "2016-08-27 12:51:00"
        }, {
          "v": 1020.61
        }, {
          "v": 30
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2016-08-27 12:54:00"
        }, {
          "v": 1020.49
        }, {
          "v": null
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2016-08-27 12:57:00"
        }, {
          "v": 1020.49
        }, {
          "v": 30.4
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2016-08-27 13:00:00"
        }, {
          "v": 1020.48
        }, {
          "v": 30.7
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2016-08-27 13:03:00"
        }, {
          "v": 1020.43
        }, {
          "v": 30.6
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2016-08-27 13:06:00"
        }, {
          "v": 1020.39
        }, {
          "v": 30.5
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2016-08-27 13:09:00"
        }, {
          "v": 1020.34
        }, {
          "v": 30.9
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2016-08-27 13:12:00"
        }, {
          "v": 1020.33
        }, {
          "v": 30.5
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2016-08-27 13:15:00"
        }, {
          "v": 1020.28
        }, {
          "v": 30.8
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2016-08-27 13:18:00"
        }, {
          "v": 1020.28
        }, {
          "v": 30.8
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2016-08-27 13:21:00"
        }, {
          "v": 1020.28
        }, {
          "v": 31
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2016-08-27 13:24:00"
        }, {
          "v": 1020.23
        }, {
          "v": null
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2016-08-27 13:27:00"
        }, {
          "v": 1020.24
        }, {
          "v": 30.7
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2016-08-27 13:30:00"
        }, {
          "v": 1020.2
        }, {
          "v": 31.3
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2016-08-27 13:33:00"
        }, {
          "v": 1020.23
        }, {
          "v": 31.3
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2016-08-27 13:36:00"
        }, {
          "v": 1020.2
        }, {
          "v": 31.3
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2016-08-27 13:39:00"
        }, {
          "v": 1020.14
        }, {
          "v": 31.3
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2016-08-27 13:42:00"
        }, {
          "v": 1020.14
        }, {
          "v": 31.1
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2016-08-27 13:45:00"
        }, {
          "v": 1020.06
        }, {
          "v": 31
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2016-08-27 13:48:00"
        }, {
          "v": 1020.06
        }, {
          "v": 31.1
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2016-08-27 13:51:00"
        }, {
          "v": 1020.03
        }, {
          "v": 31.1
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2016-08-27 13:54:00"
        }, {
          "v": 1019.98
        }, {
          "v": 31.1
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2016-08-27 13:57:00"
        }, {
          "v": 1019.97
        }, {
          "v": 31.1
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2016-08-27 14:00:00"
        }, {
          "v": 1019.9
        }, {
          "v": 31.1
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2016-08-27 14:03:00"
        }, {
          "v": 1019.89
        }, {
          "v": 31.1
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2016-08-27 14:06:00"
        }, {
          "v": 1019.75
        }, {
          "v": 31.2
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2016-08-27 14:09:00"
        }, {
          "v": 1019.8
        }, {
          "v": 31.2
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2016-08-27 14:12:00"
        }, {
          "v": 1019.72
        }, {
          "v": 31.3
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2016-08-27 14:15:00"
        }, {
          "v": 1019.64
        }, {
          "v": 31.1
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2016-08-27 14:18:00"
        }, {
          "v": 1019.6
        }, {
          "v": 31.3
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2016-08-27 14:21:00"
        }, {
          "v": 1019.6
        }, {
          "v": 31.3
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2016-08-27 14:24:00"
        }, {
          "v": 1019.55
        }, {
          "v": 31.3
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2016-08-27 14:27:00"
        }, {
          "v": 1019.55
        }, {
          "v": 31.4
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2016-08-27 14:30:00"
        }, {
          "v": 1019.49
        }, {
          "v": 31.3
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2016-08-27 14:33:00"
        }, {
          "v": 1019.46
        }, {
          "v": 31.4
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2016-08-27 14:36:00"
        }, {
          "v": 1019.44
        }, {
          "v": 31.3
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2016-08-27 14:39:00"
        }, {
          "v": 1019.36
        }, {
          "v": 31.1
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2016-08-27 14:42:00"
        }, {
          "v": 1019.41
        }, {
          "v": 31.1
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2016-08-27 14:45:00"
        }, {
          "v": 1019.33
        }, {
          "v": null
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2016-08-27 14:48:00"
        }, {
          "v": 1019.35
        }, {
          "v": 31.3
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2016-08-27 14:51:00"
        }, {
          "v": 1019.34
        }, {
          "v": 31.3
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2016-08-27 14:54:00"
        }, {
          "v": 1019.29
        }, {
          "v": 31.4
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2016-08-27 14:57:00"
        }, {
          "v": 1019.22
        }, {
          "v": 31.3
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2016-08-27 15:00:00"
        }, {
          "v": 1019.24
        }, {
          "v": null
        }]
      }]
    });


    var formatPattern = '#,##0.0';
    var formatNumber = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
      pattern: formatPattern
    });
    formatNumber.format(dataTable, 1);
    formatNumber.format(dataTable, 2);

    var options = {
      legend: {
        position: 'none'
      },
      interpolateNulls: true,
      vAxis: {
        format: formatPattern
      }
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));
    chart.draw(dataTable, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));

    options.theme = 'material';
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('linechart_core'));
    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
  },
  packages: ['corechart', 'line']
});
```

```css
div {
  padding-bottom: 24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div>Core Chart</div>
<div id="linechart_core"></div>
<div>Material Chart</div>
<div id="linechart_material"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example! But afaik (suggested http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39208271/y-axis-format-on-google-charts-dual-y-axis-line from you @WhiteHat) I need the `google.charts.Line.convertOptions` to let the vaxis has it's own format and let the tooltip to have it as well, showing the values with decimal. So I need to choose whether to have the Y-Axis with a `Numberformat` or have the `interpolateNulls` using a different chart? Cannot have both working?

Comment: sorry, hope i haven't confused you -- there are several options that simply don't work in _Material_ charts (`charts.Line`) -- some you can get to work using `convertOptions` -- but __all__ options will work when using a _Core_ chart (`visualization.LineChart`) -- unless _Material_ specific -- so to get both `NumberFormat` and `interpolateNulls` must use _Core_ -- i've added number format to the answer above...

Comment: Great! Give that man one beer! (@WhiteHat - you helped me a lot in those days!) I was able to convert the MaterialChart to ClassicChart and maintain all the needs! Last question: is there a way to format the x-Axis as well? Now it writes the whole date in format like "2016-08-28 15:00:00". Is there a way to format it smaller?
Meanwhile, thanks for all!!!

Comment: need to change first column to a real date, then use `hAxis.format`